# Use side-by-side lib versions by Maven

Tags: java, maven

Below is the rough version of my POM,

```xml
<project>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>one-java-artifact-version-X</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>one-java-artifact-version-Y</dependency>
                </dependencies> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I want the plugin to use `one-java-artifact-version-Y` but other things to use `one-java-artifact-version-X`. Is it possible to use different versions of a java artifact **side-by-side** with Maven? Specially, how to deal with the situation above?

**@EDIT**

In my case with Maven 3.0.4, `one-java-artifact-version-Y` is always shadowed by `one-java-artifact-version-X`, so the plugin fails to execute because of the undesirable dependency on `one-java-artifact-version-X` instead. However, the plugin works while other things mess up after `one-java-artifact-version-Y` being promoted to a global dependency below,

```xml
<project>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>one-java-artifact-version-Y</dependency>

        <dependency>one-java-artifact-version-X</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Results? Error Messages ?

Comment: `version-Y` is shadowed by `version-X`.

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if that is possible in this case (i.e. one conflicting with the plugin version), but with respect to regular dependency management (i.e. between 2 dependencies using 2 different versions), [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) says,

> "nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest
>   one to your project in the tree of dependencies, eg. if dependencies
>   for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A -> E -> D
>   1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a dependency to D
>   2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0

Comment: So Maven resolves the conflict by using all but one version of them, right? It doesn't solve the problem before me.

Comment: yes, maven resolution boils down to 1 version with the nearest definition. For your particular case, there might be some hack but not sure.